# VBA Dir Picking Up Ghost File In Directory Named ".." or Documents.xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I'm reasonably famaliar with using the VBA `Dir` procedure to loop through files in a folder. Usually, I don't have issues, but on a project I'm working on, the DIR is picking up a file that, as far as I can tell, does not exist. This ultimately causes my code to debug error.

Here is a screenshot of the folder containing the files.
[image]

Yet when the code tries to execute the open, it errors (always after successfully doing one file first) and says the issues is because of some file named `Documents.XLSX`. I rarely use xlsx types, so I don't know where it's pulling that name from.

[image: Error VB Shows]

Strangely, if I set VBA to `debug.print` it prints the name as ".." as opposed to the Document.xlsx name.

[image]

Does anyone know why this would happen?

I'm certain it has something to do with opening and closing the file because if I remove this action, the code `Debug.Prints` correctly with the three file names. I considered that maybe closing the file was hanging it, so I included `DoEvents` after the close, but no change. I even stopped the macro for about a minute after closing the file before running the next line of `myFile = Dir` and that still didn't solve it.

Any suggestions on why this is or how further to troubleshoot would be most helpful.

Unfortunately, I don't even have a workaround. If I set to only execute if myFile <> ".." that works to skip, but for the disappearance and reappearance of ".." is throwing off the "next" option to cause the loop to repeat indefinitely.
Code is pretty standard.

```
Dim myFile, WB as Workbook
myFile = Dir(dirPath)

Do While (myFile <> "")

'I included this for my own research
Debug.Print myFile

'Opens workbook
'This next line is where the error happens
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=dirPath & myFile)

'Macro does stuff

'Closes
WB.Close savechanges:=False
DoEvents

myFile = Dir

Loop
```

**UPDATED THANKS TO JEEPED IN COMMENTS**
I didn't think to mention that in a different module, I have a custom function that's intended to ensure that the user has entered a valid file path in a Cell. I also should mention that my VBA CODE `'do Something` is updating cells, and probably causing this custom function recalculate.

This code is....

```
Public Function isValidPath(FilePATH as String) as Boolean
   If Right(FilePATH,1) <> "\" Then FilePATH = FilePATH & "\"

   If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString then isValidPath = True

End Function
```

Who wants to earn a free ✔️??

Comment: `.` is the current 'active folder'. `..` is the parent of that folder.

Comment: So it has somehow gone out of the folder? Okay... that doesn't make sense, but let me consider that.

Comment: ACK! I know what it is!!! I will update my question and somebody can probably easily post an answer.

Comment: Every folder has a `.` and a `..` except a root folder (e.g. `c:\\`). I cannot diagnose anything further since you;'ve decided that the definition of dirPath was unimportant (btw, is was **not** unimportant).

Comment: (actually, if I remember my ms-dos 3.3 correctly, even c:\ has a `..` but I cannot remember where it points to)

Comment: @Jeeped if you want the answer, post something and I'll give it to you so i can go to bed.

Comment: Well anything I posted would just be a dupe of my comment about .. and . folders. Maybe we can write this off as typographical and delete it.

Comment: I Always check if Dir exists through `If Dir(....) <> "" then` within the module I loop through files. Also, you could have it skip hidden files looping through the 3 visible only (untested). + Bedtime? Just got out of bed :P

Comment: But I worked hard in piecing it goether!! It's not really a typographical error. It does capture the issue of *don't use a custom function that recalculates while looping through files*. I'll leave it up for now, and see how I feel in morning. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A folder will always¹ contain two things. A `.` represents itself and a `..` represents its parent.

If you use Dir with the vbDirectory argument and suffix the path with a backslash as you've done then you will return two results; a `.` and a `..`. No need for a loop; either it is there or it is not.

If you use Dir with the vbDirectory argument without a backslash suffix then you will return one result; the name of the folder. No need for a loop; either it is there or it is not.

While it is possible to have a file with no extension named what you are looking for as a folder, there cannot be a folder and a file with no extension named the same in the same parent folder. While not fail-safe, it is a reasonable conclusion and if it errors then you should probably be taking a closer look at it in any event.

To summarize, if you look for a folder with or with out a trailing backslash you will receive a non-zero-length-string as a result unless you have a singular very special circumstance.

Your 'helper' function code 'as-is' should be fine.

```
Public Function isValidPath(FilePATH as String) as Boolean

   isValidPath = cbool(len(Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory)))

End Function
```

btw, if you are a fan of walking over errors then this accomplishes the same thing with or without the trailing backslash (i.e. guarantees the folder's existence to a single sub-folder level).

```
on error resume next
mkdir FilePATH 
on error goto 0
```

---

¹  <sub>if I remember my ms-dos 3.3 correctly, even c:\ has a .. but I cannot remember where it points to.</sub>