# How do I integrate another statement in while loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

Ok so here's the background of my VBA code.
I have a code where it is automated and will execute every x seconds. I have 4 folders: Source, F1 ,F2 and Final.
The first part of my code compares files in my Source folder with my Final folder and any file that is missing between the two will be copied into F2.
Also the code is supposed to copy and paste all the files from Source folder to F1 which I don't know how to add it in my code at the moment.
Currently my code only executes the first portion which is comparing Source folder and Final folder while adding the difference to F2 folder.
I have the code for the 2nd part but I don't know how to integrate it with my while loop.
I am relatively new to VBA, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
    Option Explicit
Dim RunTimer As Date

Sub SyncFiles()
  Dim f As String
  Const SourceFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\Source\"
  Const Final = "C:\Users\Desktop\FinalFolder\"
  Const F2 = "C:\Users\Desktop\F2\"
  Const F1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\F1\"
  f = Dir(SourceFolder & "*.txt")
  
  RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

Application.OnTime RunTimer, "SyncFiles"
  
  On Error Resume Next
  While Len(f)
    GetAttr Final & f
    If Err Then
      Err.Clear
      FileCopy SourceFolder & f, F2 & f
      End If
    f = Dir()
  Wend
  While Len(f)
    GetAttr F1 & f
    If Err Then
      Err.Clear
      FileCopy SourceFolder & f, F1 & f
    End If
    f = Dir()
  Wend
End Sub
```

The part where I cant integrate is the 2nd part which is this part from the code. The code works fine when I add this first instead of my first part, which means the structure of this may be wrong?

```
While Len(f)
    GetAttr F1 & f
    If Err Then
      Err.Clear
      FileCopy SourceFolder & f, F1 & f
    End If
    f = Dir()
  Wend
```

Comment: Since the condition for both loops are the same, why not insert the second part code into the first one?

Comment: Just FYI, the first While Len(f) loop exits when Len(f) = 0 and you don't reset the value of f, so the second loop will never execute.

Comment: Do you have any other DIR as part of a function of some sort? That tripped me up once and I had to post this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889881/vba-dir-picking-up-ghost-file-in-directory-named-or-documents-xlsx